# Hide a div at end of <section>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know how to show or hide a div.
When scroll to sec 2;
The 'banner' div has to be visible at the beginning of sec2 (section)
and hide when sec2 section ends.
But don't how to check if (in this case) 'sec2' is ended.
This has to be sticky? under the (sticky) menubar.

This is a not the real source, but the same scripts and css settings.
Because the real page is to big to publish here.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var showbar = $('#sec2').height();
    var showbar = showbar -25;

    if ( scrollTop > showbar) { 
        $("#banner").fadeIn(700);
    }else{
        $("#banner").fadeOut(250);
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    height:100%;
}

section {
    display: block;
    color:white;
    height:100%;
    
    
}

#menubar{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  
  height:25px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:1000;
  
}

#menubar a {
  margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#menubar a:hover {
  color:yellow; 
}

#sec1 {
  background-color:red;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color:blue;
}

#sec3 {
  background-color:green;
}

#banner {
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 25;
  height:35px;
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menubar">
      <a href="#sec1">Section 1</a>
      <a href="#sec2">Section 2</a>
      <a href="#sec3">Section 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">Show this div only in section 2</div>
    <section id="sec1"> bla  </section>
    <section id="sec2"> bla bla </section>
    <section id="sec3"> bla bla bla </section>
  </div>
</div>
    <script>
        function scrolled(o){
            //visible height + pixel scrolled = total height
            if(o.offsetHeight + o.scrollTop == o.scrollHeight){
                var x = document.getElementById("#banner");
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }}
    </script>
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Set the header position value to sticky, and then conditionally change `display: none` based on where section 3 passes the top threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly changed the structure of your html, wrapping the sections tags in div:

```
<div class="sections">
    <section id="sec1"> bla  </section>
    <section id="sec2"> bla bla </section>
    <section id="sec3"> bla bla bla </section>
</div>
```

This is done so that the stickiness rule works at the height of all sections. And he also made adjustments to the css.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var showbar = $('#sec2').height();
    var showbar_out = $('#sec3').height();
    var showbar = showbar /*-25*/;
    
 if ( scrollTop > showbar && scrollTop < showbar_out) { 
        $("#banner").fadeIn(700);
    }else{
        $("#banner").fadeOut(250);
    }       
    
    
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    /*height:100%;*/
}

.sections {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

section {
    display: block;
    color:white;
    /*height:100%;*/
    height: 100vh;
}

#menubar{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  
  height:25px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:1000;
  
}

#menubar a {
  margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#menubar a:hover {
  color:yellow; 
}

#sec1 {
  background-color:red;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color:blue;
}

#sec3 {
  background-color:green;
}

#banner {
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
  height:35px;
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menubar">
      <a href="#sec1">Section 1</a>
      <a href="#sec2">Section 2</a>
      <a href="#sec3">Section 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">Show this div only in section 2</div>
    <div class="sections">
    <section id="sec1"> bla  </section>
    <section id="sec2"> bla bla </section>
    <section style="height: 200vh" id="sec3"> bla bla bla </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script>
       /* function scrolled(o){
            //visible height + pixel scrolled = total height
            if(o.offsetHeight + o.scrollTop == o.scrollHeight){
                var x = document.getElementById("#banner");
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }}*/
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is better, But still got the problem that the banner div doesn't hide when section 3 starts.  But it works when going to section 1.

Comment: Ah ... exactly. There is such a flaw. I'll fix this a little later.

Comment: you my hero.. looks like very simple solution.

Comment: edit * found that problem.. there is stil a little bit of section 2 visible if you go from sec1 to sec3. *
oh :( not yet.. something weird is going on. If i'm going from section 1 to section 3. the banner shows and starts blinking. And when i change from section it stays blinking.

Comment: Everything works well for me. Most likely the blinking you are talking about is a `fade` animation that does not have time to complete due to a delay.

Answer (score 1):

Make the banner inside the section and use `position:fixed` for it and with a clip-path trick you hide it from the outside:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

#menubar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#menubar a {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menubar a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

#sec1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path:inset(0); /* this will keep the banner inside sec2 */
}

#sec3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#banner {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  height: 35px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menubar">
      <a href="#sec1">Section 1</a>
      <a href="#sec2">Section 2</a>
      <a href="#sec3">Section 3</a>
    </div>
    <section id="sec1"> bla </section>
    <section id="sec2">
      <div id="banner">Show this div only in section 2</div>
      bla bla </section>
    <section id="sec3"> bla bla bla </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk for helping, this is a solution. But the answer from sergey kuznetsov works exactly,how it has to.